# Execute a long running task in background and show progress until it's not complete in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, command-line-interface, rust-tokio

I have a CLI-based application that performs long computations in the background. While it performs the background computation, I want to display progress in the console, and once the background task is complete I want to use the return code to display the correct message ex: update success/ failed, etc.

Here's an example of how the application will look like:

> Updating the driver
>
> ................................
>
> Update completed successfully

To execute the task `async fn update_device() -> u8{ }` in the background I can use async function and call tokio::task::spawn() on it, and call .await on the JoinHandle. But I want to know how can I show the progress, while the updates are going.

I checked the `JoinHandle` in tokio has a function `is_finished()`, but I don't know how to call it or use it for this purpose.

I want to display progress in the console, and once the background task is complete I want to use the return code to display the correct message ex: update success/ failed, etc.

When I try to call `is_finished` before `await`ing like this:

```
async fn update_device() -> u8{
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_sec(5000)).await;
}

fn test(){

    println!("Updating the driver");
    let handle = tokio::task::spawn(update_device());

    loop{
        if handle.is_finished() == true{
            break;
        }
        print!(".")
    }

    println!("Driver Update succesfully");
}


fn main() {
    test()
}
```

I get the error

```
there's no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_finished` has to be called from within a running runtime, otherwise there is nothing that could advance the `Future` and thus it would always return the same `false`, the easiest to adapt your code is to use the attribute `#[tokio::main]`:

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use core::time::Duration;
#[tokio::main]
async fn test() {
    let h = tokio::task::spawn(update_device());
    while !h.is_finished() {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(250)).await;
        print!(".");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    }
    println!();
    if h.await.unwrap() == 0 {
        println!("Update completed successfully");
    } else {
        println!("Update failed");
    }

}

async fn update_device() -> u8 {
    println!("Updating the driver");
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
    0
}

fn main() {
    test()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=191df67c316473d2fa2e4e76e4693445)

Answer (score 2):

you can try using tokio select macro. It Waits on multiple concurrent branches, returning when the first branch completes, cancelling the remaining branches.

Sample code:

```
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::time::Duration;
use std::io::Write;
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::select! {
        _ = do_actual_update_async() => {
            println!("\ndriver installation completed")
        }
        _ = looper() => {
            panic!("never come here")
        }
    };
    println!("Completed");
}
async fn do_actual_update_async() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
   println!("Updating the driver.......\n");
    let h = tokio::task::spawn(async { update_device().await });
    h.await?
}

async fn looper() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    loop {
        
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
        print!(".");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    }
}

async fn update_device() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    // actual implementation of update device
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(20)).await;
    Ok(())
}
```